# onload action just work one time at the same page on WebKit based Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I just implement a jquery code to let my picture in a div at vertical-middle location,the code is as follows.

```
function setImgMiddle(img) {  
    var $img = $(img),  
        $panel = $(img).parent();

    var img_width = $img.width(),img_height = $img.height(),
        panel_width = $panel.width(), panel_height = $panel.height(); 

    if(panel_width/panel_height < img_width/img_height){  
        $img.width(panel_width);  
        $img.css('margin-top', (panel_height - $img.height()) * 0.5);  
    }
    $img.fadeIn(100);  
}
```

and I use folllowing code in my index.html.

```
<img id="pic_in" class="lazy" onload="setImgMiddle(this)" src="<?php echo catch_first_image() ?>"  alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"  width="200px"  />
```

because I use this in wordpress, so it could  explain src and alt thing

The problem is that  I have two part of reference in the same page at different location ,however, the onload action is fired just once( the first one at the front), the second one do not work, I search the internet, they say I should new a Image() first, But I am a beginner, and feel a little confuse about their code, and don't understand it. So I need help thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in CSS with no javascript needed:

```
HTML:

<div class="center_image_box ">
    <div class="aligner">
        <img src="image.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center_image_box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
}

.aligner {
    display: block;
    font: 0pt/0 a;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60px;
}

.aligner:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.aligner img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As for your javascript, you need to preload both images:

```
<script>

    function preloadImage(src, callback) {
        var image = new Image();
            image.src = "image.png";
            image.onLoad = function() {
                 callback(image);
             }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){

         var images = array();
             images[] = 'image1.png';
             images[] = 'image2.png';

         for (var i=0; i<images.length;i++) {
             preloadImage(images[i], setImgMiddle);
         }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: that css works toatolly fine, but the picture is out of shape， So I change width to max-width, and set height to auto in .aligner, but is not vertical-aligned,so the second problem is coming out, how to get a good shape of pics